# Custom Stock status when product goes below X, Product specific

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, stock, inventory

I want to show a custom stock status when a product reaches a certain amount.
The amount will be different per product and custom attributes will be added to the attribute set to get the information.

I am modifying product/view/type/default.phtml

Here is what I have:

```
$stock_limit = $_product->getstock_limit();
$actual_stock = $_product->/*the correct way to get stock?*/

        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable() && $stock_limit < $actual_stock): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Limited:') ?> <span class="in-stock1"><?php echo $this->__(' Only ' . $actual_stock . ' items in stock') ?>
        </span></p>

        <?php elseif ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span class="in-stock1"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>
        </span></p>

       <?php else: ?>
       <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
$actual_stock = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty());
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I needed. I also got $actual_stock < $stock_limit the wrong way round :)

Comment: You can upvote then for help all community users :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your code from

```
$stock_limit = $_product->getstock_limit();
$actual_stock = $_product->/*the correct way to get stock?*/
```

to following code:

```
$stock_limit = $_product->getStockLimit();
$actual_stock = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();/*the correct way to get stock?*/
```